# Unable to enable Views Slideshow: Cycle In Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I am getting the following error:

> You need to install the jQuery cycle plugin. Create a directory in
>   sites/all/libraries called jquery.cycle, and then copy
>   jquery.cycle.all.min.js or jquery.cycle.all.js into it. You can find
>   the plugin at http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle. (Currently using jQuery
>   Cycle Library Library required for Views Slideshow Cycle)

But I have done all the things it asks. I've created a folder in `drupal2/sites/all/libraries/ jquery.cycle` and included `jquery.cycle.all.js` in that folder. I have given full permission and have refreshed the cache.

Does anyone know why it is not enabling?

Comment: Did you install [Libraries](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) as a module?

Comment: Did you check the permissions of that folder? Is it accessible by the server? Maybe do a `chmod -R 777 sites/all/libraries/jquery.cycle` and check if this is indeed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your jQuery Version as it is specified that it requires jQuery v1.7.1 or later.

might be this helps you.